# Why does $0<y_1<y_2$ imply $y^{n}_{1}<y^{n}_{2}$ for every integer $n>0$?

Tags: analysis

Multiplying, or dividing both sides by $y_1$, or $y_2$ doesn't seem to get the results.

Comment: Which $n$ are you looking to prove this for?

Comment: If $n$ is a natural number, $0<y_1<y_2\Rightarrow 0<\frac{y_1}{y_2}<1\Rightarrow 0<\left(\frac{y_1}{y_2}\right)^n<1$

Comment: @πr8 for every integer $n$ > 0

Comment: Then you should include that in your original post.

Comment: @Prospect I just did. I didn't expect that would be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$ y_2^n - y_1^n = (y_2 - y_1)(y_2^{n-1} + y_2^{n-2}y_1 + \ldots + y_2 y_1^{n-2} + y_1^{n-1}) > 0 $$

being a product of positive numbers.

Comment: NB this solution only holds for positive integers $n$.

Comment: Yep, I assumed that $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Nate's and 5xum's observations are better and handle the more general case.

Comment: It looks now from the comments that OP only wanted it for that case anyway. (I +1'd regardless for the nice argument.)

Answer (score 1):

The only rule you need is:

> If $x>0$ and $a>b$, then $ax > bx$.

So, because $y_1>0$ and $y_2>y_1$ you have $y_2\cdot y_1 > y_1\cdot y_1$

Furthermore, because $y_2>0$ and $y_2 > y_1$, you have $y_2\cdot y_2 > y_2\cdot y_1$.

---

Put those two inequalities together and use transitivity and you are done with proving that $y_1^2<y_2^2$. Using induction should then help you prove that for an arbitrary $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with $$y_1^2 < y_1 y_2 < y_2^2$$ and prove for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by induction.

Answer (score 1):

For $a > 0$, the function $$f_a : y \mapsto y^a$$ satisfies $$f_a'(y) = a y^{a - 1} > 0,$$ so $f_a$ is increasing on the interval $(0, \infty)$ and in particular $0 < y_1 < y_2$ implies $$y_1^a < y_2^a .$$